# Why do E2 reactions (dehydrohalogenation) only occur when the hydrogen and leaving group are in the same plane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

E2 reactions ([dehydrohalogenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehydrohalogenation)) only occur when the hydrogen and leaving group are in the same plane.

I can't think of a reason that they would need to be in the same plane, so what is the reason for this strange phenomenon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the $\ce{C-X}$ and $\ce{C-H}$ $\ce{sp^3}$bonds break, the orbitals left behind on the two carbons will rehybidize into p orbitals and form the pi bond in the forming double bond.  For these two p orbitals to form a pi bond they must be in the same plane (or very close).

This is illustrated in the following figure.  This is called the anti-periplanar conformation (the soon-to-be p orbitals are in the same plane and arranged ~180° with respect to each other) and is the preferred geometry for E2 elimination.

[image]

[image source](http://www.mhhe.com/physsci/chemistry/carey/student/olc/graphics/carey04oc/ref/ch05eliminationreactions.html)

Elimination can also occur from the syn-periplanar conformation (the soon-to-be p orbitals are in the same plane and arranged ~0° with respect to each other) as shown below, but this conformation is slightly less favored.

[image]

This is why in molecules where the $\ce{C-X}$ and $\ce{C-H}$ bonds are locked in a conformation (perhaps by an inflexible ring system) where they are oriented 90° apart, E2 elimination becomes very difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: Why is $180^\circ$ orientation of p orbitals is preferred to their $0^\circ$ orientation with respect to each other?

Comment: @Abcd 1) electronic factors - imagine how the original sp3 orbitals transform to p-orbitals as the hydrogen and LG move further away and note that there is more\better  overlap (on both the top and bottom lobes) between the forming p-orbitals in the 180° case as compared to the 0° case  2) steric factors - will favor the 180° elimination particularly if "B" and LG are large.

Comment: @ron If syn-periplanar conformation just has higher activation energy this doesn't mean that in a reacting sample there is no possibility that two molecules will react with that conformation, right?

Comment: @adosar Correct.  As I noted in my answer, "Elimination can also occur from the syn-periplanar conformation...but this conformation is slightly less favored".