# Dehydrohalogenation Reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why do dehydrohalogenation reactions mostly follow the E2 mechanism? Doesn't the base play a role in deciding whether a particular reaction will follow E1 or E2? For eg, a strong base would favor e2 and a weak one would favor E1. In fact, if dehydrohalogenation reactions follow the E1 mech, a carbocation would be formed which can undergo rearrangement to the carbon directly attached to the halogen, and can undergo resonance with it. Why doesn't that happen?

[image]

Also, in this question, for example, E1 reaction seems to be major. Why is that so, and what conditions have to be satisfied in dehydrohalogenation reactions for them to be E1?

Comment: I did not really understand what your actual concern is here?
"Doesn't the base play a role in deciding..." YES, the base is one of the main conditions that decides what kind of reaction is carried out.
This might seem a little weird but let me 'personify' the reagents and explain how my teacher once explained this to me:
A strong base won't wait for the carbocation to form, as a result the reaction proceeds in a concerted single step.
A weak base won't attack until a stable carbocation is formed.
The other conditions like presence of a protic solvent is also sigificant.

Comment: To answer the last question - "Why doesn't that happen?"
It is quite possible that kinetically stable products are favoured over thermodynamically stable ones. It just depends on whatever is available to satisfy the conditions.

Comment: Yes, the point about the base makes sense. But, I came across a question recently, where they asked for the dehydrohalogenated product (without mentioning the base), and the options had both E1 and E2 products. Since most dehydrohalo rxns are E2, i went for that, but the given answer was the E1 product. So, my doubt is: how do we decide which pathway it will follow? And that also led me to wonder why most dehydrohalo rxns are E2? If you google for dehydrohalogenation reactions, almost all websites mention that they are E2 reactions. Why?

Comment: http://home.iitk.ac.in/~madhavr/CHM102/Lec13.pdf

Comment: It gets very complicated to answer it in general. There should be a loop hole to figure out if the base/reagent wasn't mentioned.

Comment: Look for cues like the type of carbocation formed. For example, I've encountered questions without a base mentioned for Sn1 & Sn2. The stability of the intermediates will be relative here as ter-carbocation is stable in one type of nucleophilic but not preferable for the other type. Similar way, check the RDS outcomes to decide for now. Or maybe post the question that you were talking about.

Comment: @Desai kinetic and thermodynamic stability depends solely on temperature, right? if the temperature is low, kinetic control is favored, and thermo otherwise, if im not mistaken. So, i dont really see how that is relevant here...

Comment: @Desai I have edited my question. Also, in nucleophilic sub rxns, sn1 favors tert and sn2 favors primary, so that can be used to distinguish among them. But, for elimination, both e1 and e2 favor teriary...

Comment: @Buraian in that ppt too, they have just mentioned that the most common pathway is E2, for dehydrohalo rxns. My doubt is why? And "most common" doesnt mean always, so when will E1 product be favored?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27380/102629

Comment: @cngzz1 that doesnt really answer my question.. any help?